# how to direct website host to access `index.html` inside a folder

Tags: javascript, html

So I hosted my website but my `index.html` file is inside a folder so every time i search my domain i have to navigate through the file directory and open the `index.html` file to get access of the website. Is there any way to direct the domain to `index.html` directly inside the host, or the only way to do that is to have the index.html file outside the folder when hosting cause if that is the case then i'm going to have to change all the url's that direct to the index file in my base code.

Comment: There is, but how depends on webserver.  Apache (which is popular) can allow redirection using `.htaccess`-files if you want something to search for. But if you want a specific answer then you need to be more specific.

Comment: `npm run build` it will create dist folder and bundles your whole app into index page, that you can launch or deploy easily (gh-pages deploy), generally index page is in parent directory inself

Comment: "my index.html file is inside a folder" / "direct the domain to index.html directly inside the host" - don't you mean "inside a folder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of solutions to this problem.  But they all depend on your hosting situation.  If you aren't controlling your server then this would make your website work as is.

Put an index.html inside the root folder
With a barebones HTML file that contains a metaredirect

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/folder_that_has_homepage" />
```

Honestly, I would probably just do a find and replace to fix your paths though.

Comment: do you think the load time to the website would be affect if redirected?

Comment: This is a client side redirect.  It's going to be the slowest kind of redirect.  But it's also going to affect load time very little.

Comment: It's not the best solution. But it's the easiest.  If you are running Apache, it would load faster with a .htaccess redirect.

Comment: It redirects at a server level. It checks where to redirect to before the browser ever receives any information.  A meta redirect is sent to the browser, then loaded and redirected.  The client machine does the work instead.