# how to redirect http to https plus redirect `index.html` to another html page in .htaccess together?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, web-hosting

I have a code in .htaccess that redirects http to https but I also want to add a code that redirects the `index.html` page to another html page. Is there a way to do both together in `.htaccess`. Code provided below.

http to https code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

index.html to another html page code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is your HTTP to HTTPS redirect currently working OK? Have you tried the directives above? What specifically is the problem? "that redirects the index.html page" - But what is the URL you are actually requesting? You directive would redirect requests for `/`, not `/index.html`.

Comment: yes my http to https redirect works fine but i also wanted to add code that redirects to another html page on website load. Base problem is <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63258322/how-to-direct-website-host-to-access-index-html-inside-a-folder>

Comment: I'm not convinced that an external "redirect" is really what you want to do. The problem you are seemingly trying to solve is that your application/website is linking to one URL, but you want to serve that file from a different location? An _internal rewrite_ might be preferable, or simply changing the directory index document - these are both hidden from the client. What is the _exact_ URL you are linking to that you want to redirect?

Comment: The code you posted is a redirect from A to B - so what is no working exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
> RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
> ```

Yes, this is an external redirect and redirects from `http(s)://example.com/` to `http://example.com/index.php`. However, you are redirecting to HTTP, not HTTPS and you are redirecting to `index.php`, whereas you stated `index.html` in your question. There wouldn't seem to be a need to check the requested hostname, unless you have mutliple domains and specifically only want to redirect one instance.

Unless you plan to implement HSTS then include this redirect before your general HTTP to HTTPS redirect and include the canonical hostname in your HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect / or /index.html TO /dir/index.html (HTTPS)
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ https://example.com/dir/index.html [R=302,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

However, having read at your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63258322/how-to-direct-website-host-to-access-index-html-inside-a-folder), an external "redirect" might not be the correct solution for your problem. It sounds like you are perhaps "incorrectly" linking to a file in the document root, when you should be linking to a file in a subdirectory? (Really, you should correct your internal links if this is the case...) However, a workable solution might be to *internally rewrite* the request to the desired URL-path or to change the `DirectoryIndex` if you are linking to the document root directory. This is entirely hidden from the user/client - the user sees URL A only, but you are in fact serving URL B. But this will depend on how your site is structured.

An external redirect, on the other hand, physically sends the user/browser to URL B. They see both URL A (the link they click on) and URL B (the URL they are being redirected to) - as does a search engine bot. The browser needs to make two requests. This is potentially slower for users and places more work on your server (not much more, but it is still more).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do your http --> https first because that applies both to the original and the redirect for secure communication.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Now you can apply your redirect to `index.php`

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
     </IfModule>
```

You can adjust the `-f` and `-d` to include `!` and/or change the filename type to suit your specific needs.

Comment: `%{HTTPS} !=on` - I'm wondering why you've changed the HTTP to HTTPS code as posted in the question. For all we know that is already working OK. The second code block you've posted is a front-controller pattern - not a simple "redirect", that the OP appears to be asking for?

Comment: You make a valid point that the HTTP to HTTPS code is likely already working as designed. It was somewhat unclear why the OP included that portion of the code in the question; it seemed to imply a potential modification of the code in question, rather than just the htacess file in general. This would likely complicate the situation further. Since there was no mention of a specific CMS, I provided a version that could be applied across multiple types of websites.

Comment: Once again with the second code block I simply tried to provide a design that could be modified as necessary. But perhaps I left too much room for error? I enjoyed your post by the way. Thank you for the pointers, I shall try to be more specific.

Comment: "unclear why the OP included that portion of the code in the question" - admittedly there are several things about the question that are unclear, although I believe the intention behind including the existing directive(s) was to know how these would interact with the "new" redirect. Conflicts with existing directives is a common cause of error in `.htaccess`, so knowing the existing directives is a good thing and is often a requirement to solving more complex issues. Cheers.